# The `#if WINDOWS_APP` directive never runs in a Universal Windows App solution

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store, win-universal-app

in a my old Windows App solution I have now added the support for Windows Phone (by VS Express 2013 Update 3) but into the Shared project the blocks `#if WINDOWS_APP` never run: the `WINDOWS_APP` directive is not recognized but `WINDOWS_PHONE_APP` works correctly.
I must use `#if !WINDOWS_PHONE_APP` instead of `WINDOWS_APP` ... why? how can I use `WINDOWS_APP` in this solution?

Thanks.

Comment: #if directives don't "run", they get compiled.  It is not capable of detecting the real device at runtime.  A Universal App project generates multiple binaries, one for each project, it is up to you to deploy the correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Project Properties (Windows8.1 project) the "Conditional compilation symbols" box did not contain the `WINDOWS_APP` string.

Now I have added `WINDOWS_APP` for all kinds of configuration so that the box contains in each case exactly:

`NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_APP`

and so everything works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `#if NETFX_CORE` instead for Windows 8 apps, or `#if WINDOWS` for desktop apps

Comment: Unfortunately in this case `#if NETFX_CORE` is always true even when I set startup project Windows Phone